# How to enter tty1-6 in Linux in virtual-box in Linux host

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, tty

I installed a virtual box in my Ubuntu host, and then installed another Ubuntu on my virtual box. Everything is alright except when I try to enter tty1-6 in the virtual one, I just enter tty1-6 in my host, no matter the virtual Ubuntu has been focused by my mouse or not. How can I enter tty1-6 in my virtual Ubuntu?

Comment: how do you change between ttys?

Comment: CTRl-ALT-Fx with x the number of the TTY

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `right Ctrl key + F1` as described [here](http://ubuntu.5.x6.nabble.com/How-to-switch-to-TTY-in-VirtualBox-td4358226.html)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using CTRL-ALT-Fx, you need to use the host key : it would be RIGHTCTRL-ALT-Fx. It's because the Right-CTRL key is the host CTRl key.